# I am not able to load the page when my user is in shanghai and operating one the application page with Win8.1 and IE11.x

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-11, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-10

I am not able to load the page when my user is in Shanghai region and operating one the application page with Win8.1 and IE11.x.[image: error file loading the page]

Comment: From the console, It looks like you have many JS errors and HTML warnings in your app. I assume that the output will be same with other browsers too. I want to confirm with you that, Are you able to open the same web page with IE on your machine? Are you able to access the page with other browsers? Do you get any error on your machine with IE? If you get same errors on your machine than you need to correct the errors in your code. Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions, If needed.

Comment: Hello @Deepak-MSFT : Yes it is working fine for all other machines/browsers/windows. Just problem with that specific region machines.

Comment: If possible for you than you can try to share the URL of that problematic web page. I will try to access the web page from that region and try to check for the issue. Without producing the issue, It is hard for us to provide any suggestion for said issue.